# Button with Image Background Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new to Flutter programming and I want to ask is it possible to make image as button background flutter? Here's my image asset:

```
  final _backgroundButton = new AssetImage("assets/background_button.png");
```

and here's my button:

```
RaisedButton(
          child: const Text('LANJUTKAN'),
          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,

          elevation: 0.0,
          splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
          onPressed: () {
               // Perform some action
          },
),
```

Anyone know how to do it? it's okay for me to change the raised button to flat button or anything else as long as I can set image as background. Thank you!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

the "RaisedButton" is a material component , its take it shape depends on "material design" roles  , you can create your own custom button widget

```dart
    GestureDetector(
      child: Container(
       width:120,
       height: 40,
       decoration: BoxDecoration(
         color: Colors.black,
         image: DecorationImage(
           image:AssetImage("assets/background_button.png"), 
           fit:BoxFit.cover
         ),
       child: Text("clickMe") // button text
       )
      ),onTap:(){
       print("you clicked me");
      }
    )
```

Comment: child: Text("clickMe") is for Container

Comment: Anyone using this solution should also wrap with Semantics() and add support for keyboard focus to maintain accessibility.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone else come here looking for this, MaterialButton works perfectly.

```
      MaterialButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        textColor: Colors.white,
        splashColor: Colors.greenAccent,
        elevation: 8.0,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/button_color.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text("SIGN OUT"),
          ),
        ),
        // ),
        onPressed: () {
          print('Tapped');
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom widget

```
Expanded( child: Container( child: ConstrainedBox( constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(), child: Ink.image( image: AssetImage( 'path/the_image.png'), fit: BoxFit.fill, child: InkWell( onTap: null, ), ), ), ), ),
```

Or

In Raised button use Image() as a child instead of Text(). If both text and image are required just use Row() or Column() widget as a child.

If just an icon is required in a button use IconButton instead of RaisedButton

Answer (score -1):

As @pskink mentioned change your RaisedButton child from Text to Image, like this

```
RaisedButton(
          child: const AssetImage("assets/background_button.png"),
          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,

          elevation: 0.0,
          splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
          onPressed: () {
               // Perform some action
          },
),
```

But if you want both Text and Image then use Column or Row as child of RaisedButton and put both as children,