# Creating button with custom backgrouind and text

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a custom button that has image as a background, however I am facing a problem and getting unwanted effect of button being small and centered on the image. Whats the best way to do this? Also it would be best if it didn't have any the background color effect on click.

[image]

```dart
         Container(
                                width: double.infinity,
                                height: 40,
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/btn_bg.jpg')
                                  )
                                ),
                                child: TextButton(
                                  child: Text("test"),
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                )
                              ),
```

Comment: Did you try with icon button

Answer (score 0):

[copied]
The "RaisedButton" is a material component, its take it shape depends on "material design" roles , you can create your own custom button widget.
Link: [Button with Image Background Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55216108/button-with-image-background-flutter)

```
 GestureDetector(
  child: Container(
   width:120,
   height: 40,
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
     color: Colors.black,
     image: DecorationImage(
       image:AssetImage("assets/background_button.png"), 
       fit:BoxFit.cover
     ),
   child: Text("clickMe") // button text
   )
  ),onTap:(){
   print("you clicked me");
  }
)
```

for more information on GestureDetector
Link: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html